# In PowerShell granting full permissions to a file and a directory

Tags: powershell, permissions, powershell-cmdlet

So I'm trying to learn PowerShell, and I don't actually know how to give full permissions to a directory and its files inside. Searching information I've found that the icacls command is the most useful tool to give permissions, and I've tried something like this, but it returns me an error saying that OI is not a cmdlet.
My script is the following:

```
param(
[int]$nIteration,
[string]$directory
)

$n = 0
$name = "file"
while ($n -ne $nIteration)
{
    New-Item -path . -name $name$n -itemtype "file" -value "This is a text string."
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $directory$n
    Move-Item -Path .\$name$n -Destination $directory$n
    icacls --% ".\$directory$n" /grant media:(OI)F

    $n = $n+1
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Note: media is my user.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell parser thinks that `()` is a separate expression to be evaluated before invoking `icacls.exe`.

Use the stop-parsing operator (`--%`) to process the arguments as strings:

```
icacls --% "C:\users\media\desktop\p1pow" /grant media:(OI)F
```

The `--%` operator will also disable string expansion, so use it *after* arguments with variables and subexpressions in them:

```
icacls ".\$directory$n" --% /grant media:(OI)F
```

---

See [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) for more information

Comment: Now it says that the system can't find the specified file :/

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the `p1pow` directory exists?

Comment: edited the post with my actual script, I guess that may help

Comment: @magalenyo I've updated the answer to show how you can handle that

Comment: ok... So I tried that and still gives me a message:
"1 file was correctly processed; error at processing 0 files"